# Is this a known breaking change from Angular 2 to Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I've done my best to check if this is a known breaking change but I can't see anything that directly addresses it.

In Angular 2 (up to 2.4.9) I could do this:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, RequestOptions, Http, URLSearchParams, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import * as debugModule from 'debug';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    private someUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/stuff';
    protected debug = debugModule('some-service');
    protected defaultHeaders = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    protected defaultParams = new URLSearchParams();
    protected defaultOptions = new RequestOptions({headers: this.defaultHeaders, search: this.defaultParams});

  constructor (){
    this.debug("Are these the same?");
    this.debug(this.defaultOptions.search == this.defaultParams);
  }

}
```

...and it would output:

```ts
some-service: Are these the same?
some-service: true
```

If I do NOTHING but upgrade everything to Angular 4.0.1 I now get this:

```ts
some-service: Are these the same?
some-service: false
```

Why are these no longer the same objects?  This breaks my application as I was using `defaultParams` to pass around and augment the search parameters in some cases (like adding a user's id).  I guess I can fix this but passing around `defaultOptions` and manipulating it, but it changes my application in quite a few places.

I didn't see this anything that would cover this in anything I've read around upgrading from Angular 2 to Angular 4.

What was the change that made it so `RequestOptions` creates a copy of what you pass it rather than a reference (or whatever is going on here)?

As requested, my `package.json` file.  Yes I have typescript in the dependencies section rather than devDependencies - there is a reason for that for the moment that has nothing to do with this question:

```ts
{
  "name": "my-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run clean && tsc && npm run moveassets && NODE_ENV=production ./moveConfig && NODE_ENV=production forever start -a -l front.log -e front-err.log server.js",
    "startdev": "npm run clean && tsc && npm run moveassets && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"npm run watchassets\"  ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall-old": "typings install",
    "postinstall": "npm run moveassets && chmod +x moveConfig",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "clean": "rm -rf build/*",
    "typings": "typings",
    "moveassets": "rsync -a --include='*.css' --include='*.html' --include='*.png' --include='*/' --exclude='*' ./app/ ./build/",
    "watchassets": "onchange 'app/**/*.css' 'app/**/*.html' -e 'build/*'  -v -- npm run moveassets",
    "watch-css": "node-sass -w app/**/*.scss -o app/**/"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/async": "^2.0.38",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.39",
    "@types/debug": "0.0.29",
    "@types/express": "4.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/node": "0.0.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "^0.1.6",
    "angulartics2": "1.6.3",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "debug": "2.6.0",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "forever": "^0.15.3",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.10.10",
    "ng2-google-place-autocomplete": "^1.4.2",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "1.0.2",
    "primeng": "1.1.4",
    "randomcolor": "0.4.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.42",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "zone.js": "0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "2.2.0",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "node-sass": "3.13.1",
    "onchange": "3.2.1",
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you put your code in the ngOnInit method?

Comment: I can put it anywhere - in method calls, doesn't matter.  I just posted it like this because it was the minimal example.  in Angular 2.4.9 they are always the same object, and in Angular 4.0.1 they never are.

Comment: Check typescript versions

Comment: Can you please provide your package.json to make sure you updated everything properly.

Comment: Typescript is version 2.2.2 in both cases.

Comment: @Ploppy sure - added.  It is obviously a lot bigger than what would be required to show this issue but I was hesitant to strip it down in case I removed something that might cause the issue.

Comment: rxjs and zone.js don't seems to be up to date, there could be more. Try updating your dependencies, you can use a tool such as npm-check-updates. It could possibly resolve your issue.

Comment: I'll do what you ask, but I first noticed this problem in a project created with Angular CLI that started out with version 4.0.1.  I was migrating my code in when I saw this issue - but that project would have had the correct dependencies (or angular cli has a problem).  I'll check it out though, but I doubt it is going to make any difference.

Comment: 4.0.0-beta.0  simplify URLSearchParams creation https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/90c223591f1ea403e08fd52afa2043d10bbf02dc

Comment: http://take.ms/4B5Uj

Comment: Well - if I assume it is a copy and not a reference and just use `defaultOptions.search` where I would have used `defaultParams` it all works - so looks like this was a breaking change for some applications.